# Linux distribution that doesn't allow games and sites like yt

Tags: software-recommendation, internet

I'm to much drawn to games and YouTube films and music.

I wonder whether there is a Ubuntu flavour or configuraton which does not allow to me play anything and make it so that websites can display only text version and can't play things like YouTube

Comment: What about Ubuntu Server? All CLI all the time. Use Lynx as your browser?

Comment: Distro recommendations are off-topic on this site. Because it is basically Ask anything Ubuntu.

Comment: Distros recommendations are off topic, but official Ubuntu flavor recommendations are not off topic, so I'm voting to leave this question open in the expectation of receiving answers that are relevant to the Ubuntu community.

Comment: Though you can strip down Ubuntu to a point that makes it more difficult and less rewarding to indulge in video games, you'll always be able to play them on a system as long as it remains useful. There are tons of exciting games for the terminal or for terminal-based web browsers.

Answer (score 4):

### Install Xubuntu Core or Lubuntu Core

There's no distribution that's set up specifically to prevent the installation of games, but you can set one up to make it harder.

First off, you can choose an Ubuntu-based distribution that doesn't include games. You can also have both an admin account and a normal account, so that only the admin account can easily install things like games.

1. Get [the minimal install ISO](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD#A64-bit_PC_.28amd64.2C_x86_64.29_.28Recommended.29), which requires an Internet connection while you're installing
2. Burn it to a CD, DVD, or USB drive
3. Boot from it
4. Follow the prompts to customize it a bit
5. When it asks for your name and username, enter `admin`, not the username you'd like to use normally, enter a password that you don't normally use, write the password down, and put the password somewhere safe
6. When the `Software selection` menu comes up, select `standard system utilities` and either `Xubuntu minimal installation` or `Lubuntu minimal installation` (do **not** install `Xubuntu desktop` or `Lubuntu desktop`)

### Add your normal user

1. Log in as `admin`
2. Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
3. Run `sudo adduser <username>`, replacing `<username>` with your normal username
4. Enter the details requested, using your normal password for the new password

### Install necessary software

The distribution you installed will have practically no software on it. If you want things like LibreOffice or anything else, you'll have to install them while logged into your `admin` account.

### Install a text-mode browser, ELinks

In order to avoid games and videos in your browser, get a text mode browser:

1. Log in as `admin`
2. Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
3. Run `sudo apt install elinks`

To run the browser:

1. Log in as your normal user
2. Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
3. Run `elinks`

Note that, even though it's in a terminal, your mouse will work to click on things. Note that, to enter text into a text field, you can't just click on it and start typing. You have to click on it, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and enter the text.